# Spring Data derived query collection anti-join

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Collection of Strings and I want to filter it to keep only the Strings that do not appear in the database.
As an example, I would like it to work like this:

```
stringRepo.saveAll(Lists.of("b","c");
Collection<String> strings = Lists.of("a","b","c");
Collection<String> filteredStrings  = stringRepo.magicQuery(strings);
//filteredStrings should contain only "a"
```

If I were using SQL, I would write something similar to this:

```
SELECT a
FROM (VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c')) AS t (a) -- this should be parametrized
EXCEPT
SELECT value
FROM table
```

or a similar query using NOT IN.

Is there a way to achieve this using Spring Data derived queries? It seems that EXCEPT is not supported and derived queries with NOT IN use the query argument as a WHERE NOT IN ... predicate argument and not as a table value constructor argument.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to achieve this using Spring Data derived queries?

No, there isn't.